# How can I transform a string variable to a categorical variable in two different datasets, keeping the same conversion?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm building a model and I have two dataframes in Pandas. One is the training data and the other the testing data. One of the variables is the country. I was thinking about using OrdinalEncoder() to convert the country column to a categorical column. E.g.: "USA" will be 1 in the new column, "Brazil" will be 2 and so on. However, I want the same conversion for the two dataframes. If "USA" in the training data becomes 1 as a categorical column, I want that "USA" in the testing data also becomes 1.

Is that possible? How so?

Thanks in advance

Comment: out of curiosity why not have it as one data frame, apply the encoder and then split the data frame into testing and training from there? 

**# create training and testing vars, testing data is 20% of df, y is the predicted feature**


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, y, test_size=0.2)

Comment: Well, I received the data already sliced in two. I could just put them together and them split again, but I was wondering if it's possible to do what I asked

Comment: in which case as @SaRa has mentioned you'd be better off using hot encoding. Because let's say you want to *numerically alphabetize* the countries, if for example the word "Canada" was in one frame but not the other then your numbering would be offset

e.g. ***df1:***
america = 1,
britain = 2,
canada = 3,
**deutschland = 4**,

***df2:***
america = 1,
britain = 2,
**deutschland = 3**,
england = 4

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is recommended to use the OrdinalEncoder when you are sure or know that there exists an 'ordered' relationship between the categories. For example, the grades F, B-, B, A- and A : for each of these it makes sense to have the encoding as 1,2,3,4,5 where higher the grade, higher is the weight ( in the form of the encoded category).

In your current case, it would be better to use a OneHot encoder for the Country column before splitting into train/test datasets.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np                                                                   
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder                                     

X_train = np.array(["USA", "Sweden", "USA"], dtype=object).reshape(-1, 1)            
X_test = np.array(["Sweden", "USA"], dtype=object).reshape(-1, 1)                    

encoder = OrdinalEncoder()                                                           
encoder.fit(X_train)                                                                 

encoder.transform(X_train)                                                    
encoder.transform(X_test)
```

In case you think that you might have unknown categories in the testing, you can record all of the categories before making a training/testing split:

```py
categories = [np.unique(np.vstack([X_train[:, [i]], X_test[:, [i]]]))                
              for i in range(X_train.shape[1])]                                      

encoder = OrdinalEncoder(categories=categories)
```